# Need to have smart thermostat wiring explained like I am 5

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

So, I have finally purchased my first house, and one of the first things I wanted to upgrade is the thermostat. The heater is ancient, and still works, as well as the a/c. Outside of a now utter lack of money to replace these aging machines, the issue, as most of you may have figured out, is the lack of a C wire. I have done enough research, and watched enough YouTube videos to understand that using a basic 24v ac external transformer, it will need to be wired between the r and c connections. My issue is that a wire already occupies that spot, and I can't find a straight forward answer on if I can double up on that wire with the external transformer, or if I need to run another set of wires to complete the connection, and break the jumper between the r and rc connection points in the thermostat to achieve my smart thermostat goal. The system is already tied into the 4 traditional wires I have seen in every one of my rentals, so that seems right to me. I just don't want to slag something with my upgrade. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring of the furnace, as well as any wiring diagram on it?